# Does the runnable class go out of scope when a java thread ends?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I create an object that implements Runnable, and I start a thread with it...

```
ArrayList<Thread> threadlist = new ArrayList<Thread>();
{
  MergeThread mmt = new MergeThread();
  Thread t = new Thread(mmt);
  threadlist.add(mmt);
  t.start();
}

t.join();
Thread t = threadlist.get(0);
```

At this point is mmt guaranteed to exist or could it have gone away if garbage collection got it.

What I am asking is if the Thread object holds on to the Runnable class after the thread has ended.

edit: there's a mistake in the above it should say
threadlist.add(t);

Comment: As far as I know, once the thread has ended, the object is out of scope, unless another object is making a reference to it.

Comment: The code doesn't seem valid since there is no t inscope where you do t.join().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source of the `Thread` class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.exit%28%29):

```
/**
 * This method is called by the system to give a Thread
 * a chance to clean up before it actually exits.
 */
private void exit() {
if (group != null) {
    group.remove(this);
    group = null;
}
/* Aggressively null out all reference fields: see bug 4006245 */
target = null;
/* Speed the release of some of these resources */
    threadLocals = null;
    inheritableThreadLocals = null;
    inheritedAccessControlContext = null;
    blocker = null;
    uncaughtExceptionHandler = null;
}
```

So the system calls `Thread#exit()` and the reference to `target` (which is a runnable the thread is running) is released.

There is also a [bug report #4006245 on bugs.sun.com](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4006245) that refers to clearing the `target` reference.

Comment: Private methods of *some* implementation of the class does not really give an authoritative answer...

Comment: It's not _some_ implementation. Is's the OpenJDK, which is a base for Sun/Oracle implementation. So I think it is authoritative to some extent. Of course, looking up something like this in a official specification would be better.

Comment: Added a link to en entry in bugs database that the source code refers to.

Comment: Code is always a good authority, certainly better than documentation :-) That's what I was looking for. The Thread object DOES give up its reference to the runnable object.

Answer (score 2):

`mmt` is added to `threadList` so it will not be garbage collected as long as `threadList` itself is reachable and still holds it, which is still the case on the last line of your code example, whether your first `t` (in the middle block) still holds a reference to it or not.

Comment: no, mmt is not added the Thread object is added, and the thread object is constructed with mmt. It's not obvious if mmt is held internally to the Thread object after the thread ends.

Comment: @stu uuuh... no: `threadlist.add(mmt)` is adding `mmt` to your list. I think there is something you misunderstand here, or the code you show is not what you mean.

Comment: my mistake, there was a typo, I have corrected it. The program wouldn't compile the other way.

Comment: @stu if `MergeThread` extends `Thread` then the code should compile. The question (and answer) is now obviously completely different.

Comment: @stu Actually, even after that correction, I still don't understand your question: the thread class does not provide a getter to access the Runnable object passed to the constructor. So whether it has been nullified or not makes no difference: you can't access it anyway...

Comment: mergethread does not extend thread. I guess I should have made that clear. You're right I can't access it, what I want to know is if there is still a reference to it or not. Is it guaranteed to be around or not?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not really clear to me. However, regarding

> ***At this point is mmt guaranteed to exist or could it have gone away if garbage collection got it.***

I can say the following: If *you* can still get hold of it, the garbage collector won't reclaim the object (and if you can't get hold of it, there's no point in worrying if the object has been GC'd or not).